# php secure password generator

Tags: php, random, passwords, generator

I have been playing with a password generator but my php is.... mediocre at best. there are lots of password generator function examples around, so i started there. I stumbled through the interface between the generator and the user input but could use some advice cleaning it up.

I would like a default value in password length but if i set one say 14 using value=14 i cant seem to change it manually. 
also my bordered box that displays the password is very small until a password is generated, how can i make it a set size?

is using post from the form to the function then bringing it back with a session the beast way?

just trying to learn!

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Password Generator</title>
</head>




      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
      <p>Just a basic password generator.</p>
      <form method="post" action="./pass.php">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><h3>Select Characters</h3></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="alpha" /> Lowercase A-Z</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="alpha_upper" /> Uppercase A-Z</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="numeric" /> Numbers (0-9)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="special" /> Special Characters (.-+=_,!@$#*%<>[]{})</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><h3 style="margin: 20px 0;">Password Length</h3></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="length" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Generate" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                  <div style="padding: 20px 0;">
                      <div>Your Password:</div>

                    <div style='border:1px black solid; font-size: 14px; font-family: monospace; padding:3px; color:#000; background-color: #D2E0E6; margin: 0;'>
                        <?php
                        echo $_SESSION['password'];
                        ?>
                    </div>

</div>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

pass.php

```
<?php
$alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$alpha_upper = strtoupper($alpha);
$numeric = "0123456789";
$special = ".-+=_,!@$#*%<>[]{}";
$chars = "";

if (isset($_POST['length'])){
    if (isset($_POST['alpha']) && $_POST['alpha'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $alpha;

    if (isset($_POST['alpha_upper']) && $_POST['alpha_upper'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $alpha_upper;

    if (isset($_POST['numeric']) && $_POST['numeric'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $numeric;

    if (isset($_POST['special']) && $_POST['special'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $special;

    $length = $_POST['length'];
}else{
    $chars = $alpha . $alpha_upper . $numeric;
    $length = 9;
}

$len = strlen($chars);
$pw = '';

for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
        $pw .= substr($chars, rand(0, $len-1), 1);

$pw = str_shuffle($pw);

session_start();
$_SESSION['password'] = $pw;

header("Location: index.php");
die();

?>
```

Comment: You can put the code in `pass.php` at the top of `index.php`, and then set the form's `action` attribute to `index.php`. That way you do not have to do a redirect, and store the password in a session. Otherwise, sessions are good. You could also use cookies, or even a GET variable (i.e. redirecting to something like `index.php?password=THE_PASSWORD`, and then grab it using `$_GET['password']`).

Comment: yes thats a good idea, all one php file makes it much easier... i thought about get but i figures for anything password related keeping the data out of the url was probably a good idea.

Comment: Is there a way to point to the php file without calling it index.php? so in the forms action attribute it loads the same php file regardless of name changes?

Comment: found it    <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>